# How to autogenerate and increment Customer ID using C# in Asp.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I neet to generate customer id on clicking the submit button in a registration form which should also be stored along with customer details in SQL database.The problem is it generates for the first id 1 and then 2,after that it remains at customer id no 2 itself.and i want it in the following format : Current Year(4 digits)+Current Month(2 digits)+Number(4 digits), eg:2015120001 but I'm getting it as 2015121.. I have tried the following code to generate the id..pls check the link [Code to generate the id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gwju.jpg)

Comment: Never use All caps. It just hurts the eyes.

Comment: Sorry I'll see to it next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store your counter in outside your method, like in SQL Server and then return the customer id. Below is a sample code:

```
private static readonly object o = new object();
public static int GenerateNextCustomerId() {
   lock (o) {
      // Write code to get the next counter from db in this method
       var counter = GetNextCounter();
       var nextCustomerId = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
                            DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month,
                            counter.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0'));

       // Write code to increment the counter and save to db in this method
       IncrementCounter();
       return int.Parse(nextCustomerId);
   }
}
```

Comment: I got the desired output, I have a clarification, the customer id is of string type here, but in my database its of int type. when insert statement is executed it will throw an error,can a conversion from string to int be done?

Comment: I have made the change to code to return the customerId as int. All you need to do is to parse the customerId to int.